# Appending URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, url-parameters

I'm trying to be able to append URL parameters when somebody selects from a dropdown list. I want somebody to be able to select a series and then select a year. I've tried several things and nothing works. I'm not very familiar with Javascript but I have managed to get one parameter to append just not checking to see if one is already there and then append another one.

Below is my code.

```
<center><select id="seasondropdown" class="scheduledropdown" size="1" name="links" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
<option value="/results">Combined</option>
<option value="/results/?series=latemodels">Late Models</option>
<option value="/results/?series=modifieds">Modifieds</option>
</select></center>

<script>

    var select = document.getElementById('seasondropdown');
    var option;
    
    for (var i=0; i<select.options.length; i++){
        
        option = select.options[i];
        if (option.value == window.location.href){
            option.setAttribute('selected', true);
            
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
<center><select class="scheduledropdown" size="1" name="year" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
<option value="/results/?year=2022">2022</option>
<option value="/results/?year=2021">2021</option>
<option value="/results/?year=2020">2020</option>
</select></center>


<script>

    var select = document.getElementById('seasondropdown');
    var option;

    for (var i=0; i<select.options.length; i++){

        option = select.options[i];
        if (option.value == window.location.href){
            option.setAttribute('selected', true);

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So, what you want is two different dropdowns on the same page and when both have a valid value, set the current URL with the parameters selected in the dropdowns?

Comment: Correct, but somebody might only select one and not the other as well.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier with a submit button. I'll post an answer of what I mean.

Comment: I agree with @NicolasRégnier.  A navigation button would be more standard and what users expect.  Having an interlock on the selects, like the current design, would not be obvious to users.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, I think it is better to have a submit button. When you click on it, the button will retrieve the value of both selects and put it as parameters in the URL. Here is what I have:

```
<center>
    <select id="seasondropdown" class="scheduledropdown" size="1" name="links">
        <option value="/results">Combined</option>
        <option value="/results/?series=latemodels">Late Models</option>
        <option value="/results/?series=modifieds">Modifieds</option>
    </select>

    <select id="yeardropdown" class="scheduledropdown" size="1" name="year">
        <option value="?year=2022">2022</option>
        <option value="?year=2021">2021</option>
        <option value="?year=2020">2020</option>
    </select>

    <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</center>

<script>

    var select1 = document.getElementById('seasondropdown');
    var select2 = document.getElementById('yeardropdown');
    
    var btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');

    btn.onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var value1 = select1.value;
        var value2 = select2.value;

        window.location.href = value1 + value2

    }
</script>
```